# Subpixel antialiasing not respected by Outlook 2018

Tags: macos, mojave, ms-office

I've only just updated to Mojave...

I'm using a non-retina external display with my 2018 Macbook Pro, so have made sure font-smoothing is checked in settings, and have run

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

this has made all text better, *except* in Outlook (16.32) where it hasn't made any difference at all. Googling hasn't come up with any hints as to if Outlook does anything weird. I've tried setting `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 3` too but to no avail.

Is there anything else I can try?

[image]